# MySQL constrain transaction for entity must finish before another can begin

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, unique-constraint

I have a table for guests, each guest with a unique name.

I have a table for guest_transactions with guest_id, status_id, arrived_time, left_time.

And a status table with a name column, populated with values (here, leaving, left).

I want to record guests as they come and go, but I'd like to have a constraint which prevents a guest from arriving twice before leaving. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: not familiar with mysql syntax but you could probably do something like this:  Add column (isCUrrentlyHere) which is true if enddate is null, false otherwise.  Set a unique constraint on your guestId/name + isCurrentlyHere column

Comment: i guess technically you could just do a unique constraint on guestId and leave date

Comment: @Kritner: Neither your first nor your second comment come even close to solving the problem. This is a problem of overlapping ranges, not identity.

Comment: @lxg not sure why you're saying that... guest: "John Smith" arrive: "12:00:00" depart: null exists in the table with a unique constraint on guest and depart, you wouldn't be able to then insert another entry with "John smith" depart: null due to a unique constraint violation unless it's implemented in a very different way from mssql (i was making an assumption as i stated i'm not very familiar with mysql)

Comment: @Kritner: Each `guest_transaction` defines a date range between `arrived_time` and `left_time`. The problem to be solved here is to avoid that two `guest_transaction`s date ranges overlap. This cannot be solved with unique constraints (in any SQL dialect AFAIK). But you're welcome to prove me wrong. ;)

Comment: @lxg http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b9c6 - granted this is mssql not mysql (it doesn't appear it would work with mysql unfortunately).  I think my interpretation of what OP is asking is different than yours.  The way i'm interpreting it is "if a guest is already here (has an arrive but doesn't have a depart), don't allow that guest to arrive again.  This fiddle demonstrates how that would work.  Unfortunately however, it won't work for OPs problem :(